# iOS 9 (13A340) remote notification not working

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios9, amazon-sns

I am testing an app on iOS 9 (13A340) on iPhone 6, mainly the remote notification part. The remote push notification generated from AWS SNS cannot be received by the app, though the same app on iOS 8 works as expected. Is this due to the beta version of the iOS 9 or?

Thanks for any tip.

/Leonard

Answer (score 0):

I have tried remaking the APSN development certificate and etc. and then it starts working, although I don't know what problem really was.

Answer (score -2):

This didReceiveRemoteNotification method may also be called if a “silent/background” notification is received. As such, you should also enable “Background Modes: Remote Notifications” in the target capabilities panel (or else you’ll see warnings in the console).

Read more: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/push-notifications-tutorial-for-ios-9/#ixzz3tH8pRbz0

[check image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KHqx.png)